Remark of the definition of $C^p$-convergence of Riemannian metrics

Definition ( $C^{p}$-convergence). Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $K\subset M$ be a compact set and let $\{g_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, $g_\infty$, and $g$ be Riemannian metrics on $M$. For $p \in \mathbb{N}$ we say that $g_n$ converges in $C^{p}$ to $g_{\infty}$ uniformly on $K$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N=N(\varepsilon)$ such that for $n \geq N$,
$$\sup _{0 \leq i \leq p}~\sup _{x \in K}~\left|\nabla^i\left(g_n-g_{\infty}\right)\right|_{g}<\varepsilon,$$
where the covariant derivative $\nabla$ is with respect to $g$.
Remark. Note that since we are on a compact set, the choice of metric $g$ on $K$ does not affect the convergence. For instance, we may choose $g=g_{\infty}$.

I can't see why the claim in the remark is true. I know continuous functions on compact sets have maximum and minimum values. But I don't know how to scale. For instance, when $p=0$,
$$\left|g_n-g_{\infty}\right|_{g}^2=[(g_n)_{ij}-(g_{\infty})_{ij}]\cdot[(g_n)_{kl}-(g_{\infty})_{kl}]~g^{ik}g^{jl}.$$
But we cannot directly scale the function $g^{ik}$ and $g^{jl}$ since the right hand side of the above equation is not a simple product, but the sum of many terms. Then I don't know what else to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
EDITED:
Let $\nabla_g$ and $\nabla_h$ be two connections. Let $C:=\nabla_g-\nabla_h$, then $C$ is a $(1,2)$-tensor field since it is $C^\infty(M)$-linear at every slot. Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth vector fields, $\omega$ be a $1$-form, $T$ be a $(1,1)$-tensor field. Note that
\begin{align*}
 (C_X\omega)Y&=((\nabla_g)_X\omega)Y-((\nabla_h)_X\omega)Y\\
 &=X(\omega(Y))-\omega((\nabla_g)_XY)-X(\omega(Y))+\omega((\nabla_h)_XY)\\
 &=((\nabla_h)_XY)\omega-((\nabla_g)_XY)\omega\\
 &=\color{red}-(C_XY)\omega.\quad\text{Note the minus sign.}
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
 |C(T)|^2&=|T_i^jC(e_j\otimes\varepsilon^i)|^2\\
 &=|T_i^jC(e_j)\otimes\varepsilon^i+T_i^je_j\otimes C(\varepsilon^i)|^2\\
 &=|T_i^jC_{jk}^le_l\otimes\varepsilon^k\otimes\varepsilon^i\color{red}-T_i^jC_{kl}^ie_j\otimes\varepsilon^k\otimes\varepsilon^l|^2\quad\text{Note the minus sign.}\\
 &=|(T_i^jC_{jk}^l-T_j^lC_{ki}^j)e_l\otimes\varepsilon^k\otimes\varepsilon^i|^2\\
 &=\sum_{i,k,l}\left|\sum_j(T_i^jC_{jk}^l-T_j^lC_{ki}^j)\right|^2\\
 &\leq2\sum_{i,k,l}\left(\left|\sum_jT_i^jC_{jk}^l\right|^2+\left|\sum_jT_j^lC_{ki}^j\right|^2\right)\\
 &\leq2\sum_{i,k,l}\left(\sum_j|T_i^j|^2\sum_j|C_{jk}^l|^2+\sum_j|T_j^l|^2\sum_j|C_{ki}^j|^2\right)\\
 &=4|T|^2|C|^2.
\end{align*}
From the above argument, if $T$ is an $(r,s)$-tensor field, then $|C(T)|^2=(r+s)^2|T|^2|C|^2$.

This ultimately boils down to the fact that the manifold is finite dimensional, and on finite dimensional vector spaces all norms are equivalent.

@AlpUzman You mean that since $T_pM$ is finite dimensional, the tensor product of $T_pM$, $T_pM\otimes\cdots\otimes T_pM$ is also finite dimensional. We are considering norms defined on $T_pM\otimes\cdots\otimes T_pM$, so they are equivalent. Now the two constants $C_1(p)$ and $C_2(p)$ in the inequality relationship of equivalent norms are functions w.r.t. $p\in K$, but $K$ is compact, so $C_1(p)$ and $C_2(p)$ have maximum and minimum.

Let $M$ be a manifold, and $g$ and $h$ be two Riemannian metrics with associated Levi-Civita connections $\nabla_g$ and $\nabla_h$.
Recall that two affine connections differ by a tensor, and let $C:= \nabla_g-\nabla_h$.
Note that, as differential operators:
\begin{align}
\nabla_g - \nabla_h &= C,\\
\nabla^{(2)}_g - \nabla^{(2)}_h  &= \nabla_g(\nabla_g-\nabla_h) + (\nabla_g-\nabla_h) \nabla_h  \\
&= \nabla_gC + C\nabla_h, \\
\nabla^{(3)}_g  - \nabla^{(3)}_h &= \nabla_g(\nabla^{(2)}_g - \nabla^{(2)}_h ) + (\nabla^{(2)}_g - \nabla^{(2)}_h )\nabla_h \\
&= \nabla_g( \nabla_g C + C\nabla_h) + (\nabla_gC + C \nabla_h)\nabla_h \\
&= \nabla^{(2)}_gC + (\nabla_gC) \nabla_h + C \nabla_g\nabla_h + (\nabla_gC)\nabla_h + C \nabla^{(2)}_h \\
&= \nabla^{(2)}_gC + (\nabla_gC) \nabla_h + C (\nabla_g-\nabla_h + \nabla_h)\nabla_h + (\nabla_gC)\nabla_h + C \nabla^{(2)}_h \\
&= \nabla^{(2)}_gC + (\nabla_gC) \nabla_h + C^2 \nabla_h + (\nabla_gC)\nabla_h + 2C \nabla^{(2)}_h.
\end{align}
That in mind, it is easy to show by induction (I leave it as an exercise) the following :

For any $k \geqslant 0$, there exists tensors $(C^k_i)_{0\leqslant i \leqslant k}$ depending only on $C$ and on its $g$-covariant derivatives up to order $k-1$ such that
$$
\nabla^{(k)}_g = \sum_{i=0}^k C^k_i \nabla^{(i)}_h.
$$

For instance, the computations above show that
\begin{align}
C^1_0 &= C, & C^1_1 &= 1, \\
C^2_0 &= \nabla_gC , & C^2_1 &= C, & C^2_2 &=1 ,\\
C^3_0 &= \nabla^{(2)}_gC, & C^3_1 &= C^2 + 2\nabla_gC , & C^3_2 &= 2C, & C^3_3 &= 1.
\end{align}
Fix $E$ a tensor bundle.
As a corollary, for any $T \in E$, the triangle inequality yields
$$
|\nabla^{(k)}_g T|_g \leqslant \sum_{i=0}^k |C^k_i|_g |\nabla^{(i)}_h T|_g.
$$
Recall that there exists a continuous map $\lambda\colon M \to (0,\infty)$ such that $|\cdot|_g \leqslant \lambda |\cdot |_h$.
Hence,
$$
|\nabla^{(k)}_g T|_g \leqslant \lambda \sum_{i=0}^k |C^k_i|_g |\nabla^{(i)}_h T|_h.
$$
Now, if $0 \leqslant k \leqslant p$ are integers, and if $K\subset M$ is compact, it follows that
\begin{align}
\sup_K |\nabla^{(k)}_g T|_g &\leqslant \sup_K \lambda \sum_{i=0}^k \sup_K|C^k_i|_g \sup_K |\nabla^{(i)}_hT|_h \\
&\leqslant \Lambda_K \sum_{i=0}^k \sup_K |\nabla^{(i)}_hT|_h \\
& \leqslant (k+1) \Lambda_K \sup_{0\leqslant i\leqslant p} \sup_K |\nabla^{(i)}_hT|_h,
\end{align}
with $\Lambda_K = \sup_K \lambda\sup_{0\leqslant i\leqslant k}(\sup_K |C^k_i|_g)>0$ independent of $T$.
It follows that
$$
\sup_{0\leqslant k \leqslant p} \sup_K |\nabla^{(k)}_g T|_g \leqslant \Lambda_{K,p} \sup_{0\leqslant k \leqslant p} \sup_K |\nabla^{(k)}_h T|_h,
$$
for some constant $\Lambda_{K,p} >0$ independent of $T$.
The result now follows.

Nice way! But in the computation of $\nabla^{(3)}_g  - \nabla^{(3)}_h$, the term $+\nabla_g \nabla^{(2)}_h-\nabla^{(2)}_g \nabla_h$ seems to missed on the right side of the first equality, and I think the Leibniz's law doesn't apply to the third equality. For the second point, I think $\nabla_g(C\nabla_h)=(\nabla_gC)\nabla_h$ but not $\nabla_g(C\nabla_h)=(\nabla_gC)\nabla_h+C\nabla_g\nabla_h$.

@HeroZhang001 The term you are referring to does not appear because you substitute $\nabla^{(2)}_g - \nabla^{(2)}_h$ with what you found before.
As for the Leibniz rule, you might be right, but I'm not sure. I wrote that in a hurry and did not check everything. The highlighted is true though!

OK, there is one last point I don't understand, which is$$|\nabla^{(k)}_g T|g \leqslant \sum{i=0}^k |C^k_i|_g |\nabla^{(i)}_h T|_g.$$I know $|T\otimes S|=|T|\cdot|S|$ is indeed true, but in our case, it seems that $C^k_i \nabla^{(i)}_hT$ is not a simple tensor product, so I'm not sure $|C^k_i \nabla^{(i)}_hT|_g=|C^k_i|_g|\nabla^{(i)}_hT|_g$.

@HeroZhang001 I overlooked this. There should be universal constants $a^k_i$ depending on the types of tensors only such that $|C^k_i \nabla^{(i)}_hT| \leqslant a^k_i |C^k_i|_h |\nabla^{(i)}_h T|_g$. As I said, I was in a hurry. I let you fill all the blanks! The overall structure is the right one to answer your question

@HeroZhang001 These constants can be obtained by looking at the continuous bilinear map $(T,T') \mapsto TT'$ on the right spaces, and where the concatenation means composition in some slot.

OK, I will try to fill the details. Thanks for your excellent idea!
